# need a regex that will higlight the word after period

Tags: regex

need regex that will higlight small case word after period ( example hello. there)
it should highlight there( as it doesn't contain  first letter cap).. this regex highlight all words "[^.]+$ (irrespective of cap and small)

Comment: Try `\.\s*\K\p{Ll}\p{L}*` (PCRE), or `(?<=\.\s*)\p{Ll}\p{L}*` for .NET / PyPi regex Python module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to highlight the lowercase word, then try this:

```
(?<=\w\.\s*)([a-z]+)
```

### Demo